# Is there a ml like language(standard ml/ocaml/f#/haskell/etc) in which list elements are option types

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming, null, ml

It seems to me like [] (empty list) and None/Nothing are so similar.
I was wondering if any of that family of languages had the basic list type where each element is an option and the tail guard is Nothing?

Is it(not done this way, in languages that have separate types) because it would make pattern matching lists overly verbose?

Comment: What would be the benefit? Defining different types for different purposes is A Good Thing.

Answer (score 5):

You have something similar in Lisp, where `nil` is used both to represent both the absence of an optional value and the empty list. You can do something like this in Haskell (and I assume most ML-like languages),

```
newtype MyList a = MyList (Maybe (a, MyList a))
```

but it's more verbose and doesn't have any obvious benefits over using its own data type.

Answer (score 4):

Hmm, not that I'm aware of.  That would be difficult for a Hindley-Milner type system, which forms the basis the type systems for those languages.  (In Haskell nomenclature) `Nothing` would have to have type `Maybe a` and `[] a` simultaneously.

Something similar (but unfortunately too unwieldy to use in practice IMO) can be constructed using a fixed point type over `Maybe`:

```
-- fixed point
newtype Mu f = In (f (Mu f))
-- functor composition
newtype (f :. g) a = O (f (g a))

type List a = Mu (Maybe :. (,) a)
```

This is *isomorphic* to what you are asking for, but is a pain in the butt.  We can make a cons function easily:

```
In (O (Just (1, In (O (Just (2, In (O Nothing)))))))
```

`In` and `O` are "identity constructors" -- they only exist to guide type checking, so you can mentally remove them and you have what you want.  But, unfortunately, you cannot physically remove them.

We can make a `cons` function easily.   We are not so lucky with pattern matching.  I can't speak for the other ML family languages, but IIRC they can't even represent higher-kinded types like `Mu`.

Comment: You know, or you could forget all that `Mu` garbage and do what @hammar said.  Sigh, still an overengineer :-)